# The number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation $\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{2x}{3}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{y}{4}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{4y}{5}\rfloor=\frac{7x}{6}+\frac{21y}{20}$,where $0<x,y<30$

---

It appears that $\frac{x}{2}+\frac{2x}{3}=\frac{7x}{6}$ and $\frac{y}{4}+\frac{4y}{5}=\frac{21y}{20}$ but $\frac{x}{2}$ and $\frac{2x}{3}$ being inside the floor function,i can not add them up directly,same problem here,i cannot add $\frac{y}{4}$ and $\frac{4y}{5}$ because they are inside the floor function.What should i do to solve it?

Comment: Then x/2, 2x/3 etc. must all be integers else the floor functions would be less?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$\Bigl\lfloor\frac x2\Bigr\rfloor\le\frac x2\ ,$$
and likewise for the other terms.  So we always have $LHS\le RHS$, and the only way they can be equal is if
$$\Bigl\lfloor\frac x2\Bigr\rfloor=\frac x2\ ,$$
and likewise for the other terms.  So
$$\frac x2\ ,\quad \frac{2x}3\ ,\quad \frac y4\ ,\quad\frac{4y}5$$
must all be integers.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: $x$must be $6,12,18,24$ and $y$ must be $20$,so there are $4$ ordered pairs $(6,20),(12,20),(18,20),(24,20)$ which satisfies the equation,Am i right?@David.

Comment: Well done, looks good to me.